# How to check if field is showing (or) hidden in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I was able to get properties and methods for formGroup.get("fieldName"), but I could not find a property to check whether the field is showing (or) hidden in angular reactive form.

Could you please help on this?

Comment: you will be using `*ngIf` or hidden attribute to show/hide, just use the variable that toggles it!

Comment: @NarenMurali : I would like to check in type script file...

Comment: if you are dynamically hiding the form element then you must be using a property from component class or some other condition depending using different properties from component class. Use those property to check if form element is hidden or not.

Comment: @ANR Please share some code, if possible a stackblitz, along with details and screenshots on what needs to be done!